# How to create any UIObject with millimeter measurements?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I need to do the measurements with millimeter instead of points or pixels. I want to add an image has a fixed size but in mm. Anyone can help me please? It is like when you have to draw a ruler, how to calculate the 1 mm between the tow lines on screen? it is really confusing and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Are you aware that 1 point is 0.3528mm? You just need to do some unit conversions.

Comment: let's say I want the image width to be 15 mm on screen .. so, I set the width to (15/0.352778)?

Comment: How about creating a view with that size, run the app on a real device, and measuring it with a ruler?

Answer (score 1):

1 Apple point is 0.352778 mm(s), you can use this site to do the conversion: https://www.conversionunites.com/converter-points-to-mm.

Comment: let's say I want the image width to be 15 mm on screen .. so, I set the width to (15/0.352778) ?

Comment: Yes, please try that.